# Java swing maximization in windows 7

Tags: java, swing, windows-7

When I drag my java swing application into upper corner of the screen in Windows 7, its fills the full screen . Is there any way to remain the same size ??

Comment: Um, that's what happens to *any* window in Win7

Comment: Did you try.  a) `setResizable(false)`? b) Disabling that aspect of your OS?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are talking about your JFrame and you can use frame.[setMaximizedBounds().](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setMaximizedBounds%28java.awt.Rectangle%29)
This, as the javadoc says,

> Sets the maximized bounds for this frame.
>
> When a frame is in maximized state the system supplies some defaults bounds. This method allows some or all of those system supplied values to be overridden.
>
> **Note,** the given maximized bounds are used as a hint for the native system, because the underlying platform may not support setting the location and/or size of the maximized windows. If that is the case, the provided values do not affect the appearance of the frame in the maximized state.